# Necesito ayuda amigos con este error

Tags: php

El[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] problema es este

> PDOstatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]

Comment: Para que te podamos ayudar por favor agrega tu código como texto

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo ver en tu imagen, puede ser por el parametro "contraseña", es posible que no este reconociendo la letra ñ en ':contraseña'.

Ese tipo de errores arroja el error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.
```

También debes tener en cuenta que las variables en PHP no pueden llevar caracteres especiales como "ñ" o tildes.